# how do I make an element in a webpage not be printed?

Tags: html, css, printing-web-page

I've made a simple "print version" for the entries in our company website. However, I am required to add a button/link for going back to the website, since, allegedly, many of our customers wouldn't think to use the back button (and, indeed, there might be some truth in that - as they kept emailing, asking for a pricelist for one entry, which was actually clearly linked to, with large underlined letters, in the description)

Okay, that's all fine and dandy - however, can I do anything to make that element not to be printed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Write a css file for printout page, and just write display:none for the elements you want to hide.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="printOut.css" media="print">
```

Yes, media = "print"

Answer (score 2):

[here](http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml) is a simple guide to print stylesheets.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS:

```
@media print
{
    .dontPrintThis, .neitherThis { display: none; }
    .printThisBigger { font-size: 120%; }
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have different stylesheets for different "media" like print, projector, screen...

See [list of media types](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types).

[This](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/) is a nice (but old) article on print stylesheets.